# How to change files extension in a directory and sub directories?

Tags: powershell

I used this :

```
Dir *.html | rename-item -newname { [io.path]::ChangeExtension($_.name, "php") }
```

to change all `*.html` to `*.php` and it works, but still the sub directories are not getting changed!

How do I apply this to files in all sub directories?

Comment: take a look at the help for `Get-ChildItem` ... your `dir` is an alias for that command. [*grin*]

Comment: Use `-Recurse`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
Get-ChildItem -Depth 5 *.html | Rename-Item -NewName { [io.path]::ChangeExtension($_.name, "php") }
```